# how to join 2 tables with same column in sql

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am having `table 1` as follows

```
Product_Id  Type
110          1
121          1
133          1
```

and `table2` as

```
Count_Id   Type   Product_ID
130         5       NULL
98          7       NULL
37          9       NULL
```

Now i am using Full join and got

```
 Product_Id  Type   Count_id   Type Product_Id
    110          1   NULL      NULL   NULL
    121          1   NULL      NULL   NULL
    133          1   NULL      NULL   NULL
    NULL      NULL   130       5      NULL
    NULL      NULL   98        7      NULL
    NULL      NULL   37        9      NULL
```

Can I get the output like this

```
Product_Id     Type   Count_id  Product_Id
    110          1   NULL      NULL
    121          1   NULL      NULL
    133          1   NULL      NULL
    NULL         5  130        NULL
    NULL         7   98        NULL
    NULL         9   37        NULL
```

Please help

Comment: JOINs only work to JOIN on field by identical value, what you want to do is to have a UNION operation on the data. It should be something like "SELECT Product_Id, Type, NULL AS Count_ID from Table_1 UNION SELECT Product_Id, Type, Count_Id from Table_2" The 'NULL as Count_Id' has to be added to the SELECT statement of the Table_1 as the table itself does not contain the column.

Comment: Yep,I got the output.thanks for ur help..

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per brokenisfixed's comment, this cannot be achieved using a `JOIN` due to the lack of comparable keys to join through. Instead you need to `UNION` the two data sets together as follows:

```
SELECT
  [Product_Id],
  [Type],
  NULL AS [Count_id],
  NULL AS Type,
  NULL AS Product_Id
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT
  NULL,
  NULL,
  [Count_id],
  [Type],
  [Product_Id]
FROM Table2;
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8691/5

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, all you need is projection.

```
select table1.Product_Id,
       coalesce(table1.Type, table2.Type) as Type,
       Count_id,
       table2.Product_Id
from ... -- your join here
```